# Retain UINavigationBar height as 64points when UIStatusBar hides

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I'm using a `UINavigationController`, which has a `UINavigationBar`.

When I call and hide the UIStatusBar, the `navigationBar` reduces in size to `44pts`. I don't want this to happen, I want it to retain the size of `64pts`.

Is this even Possible? Could I do some workaround to hard code that size?

Comment: Why? The whole point of hiding the status bar is to give you more screen space. Making the nav bar taller defeats that purpose. Though you could try setting the `titlePrompt` if you really want this feature.

Comment: @rmaddy true, but Im using custom interactive transitions between uiviewcontrollers. In this case its from a UINavigationController to a `ViewCOntroller with Statusbar hidden`. As soon as I begin transition, the Navbar awkwardly slides up making a whole lot of changes to that View.

Comment: I'd recommend you just present the VC modally, to avoid this entirely. And considering the goal is for the navbar to go away, this will do it cleanly. In the UINav doc: **"The navigation controller manages the creation, configuration, and display of the navigation bar and optional navigation toolbar. It is permissible to customize the navigation bar’s appearance-related properties but you must never change its frame, bounds, or alpha values directly."**

Comment: This solution doesn't work if your view controller is presented with a custom modal style and you can see others onscreen at the same time.

Comment: the goal was to retain navbar height, not let it go. What I ended up doing.. is just loose the UINavController entirely and add a UINavBar.